# Google UI App Script: Prevent widget from being printed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

First off, I am new to scripting/coding and this may be a novice question. 
My question is, How to hide a widget from being printed in Google UI Apps?

I have made a small app which pops open a panel of what should be printed. I have also included in that panel a "close" button to hide the panel after the user has finished printing. However, I would like to prevent the "close" button from appearing on the printed piece of paper.

Some sights have said to use "display: none". However, that also hides the "close" button from the user and prevents the user from being able to close the panel.

Answer (score 0):

In uiApp the only way is to have a separate gui for printing. ie a print link that opens in a separate tab pointing to your gui url (same doGet but with parameters like ?print=1

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a print stylesheet and do something like this:

```
#id-of-widget {display: none !important;}
```

!important is required because widgets usually add their own CSS after yours.